# By what factor would gate geometry have to be enlarged when VDD increases by some factor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, integrated-circuit

For integrated circuits, let us say that one wishes to increase  (contrary to current interests in trying to lower) operating voltage/VDD of integrated circuit.

If one increases VDD by some factor k, by what factor approximately would gate geometry need to enlarge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increasing gate geometry does not allow for a higher VDD. In CMOS integrated circuits Gate oxide breakthrough is usually the parameter which places a limit on the VDD that can be used.  What happens with smaller processing nodes (for example 40 nm vs 22 nm) is that not only the smallest gate length is decreased but also the gate oxide becomes thinner resulting in lowering the value of VDD at which breakdown occurs.